# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken enviando ajax por POST. ERROR 500

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5

Hola tengo un problema con el csrftoken al hacer una peticion ajax.

Si lo desactivo en el kernel,

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
         //   \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
```

me hace la peticion correctamente, inserta el codigo bien y muestra los mensajes perfectamente, pero si no lo desactivo(Como deberia ser), me  lanza un error 500 en cada peticion ajax, y poniendome encima de cada peticion.
La idea es ir introduciendo valores en la base de datos por ajax.
El error que lanza es este.

```
TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken
```

VISTA

```
    @if(count($errors))
                        <div class="alert alert-danger">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>

                        @foreach($errors->all() as $errores)
                            <p><strong>{{$errores}}</strong></p>
                        @endforeach
                        </div>
                    @endif

{!! Form::open(array('route'=>'pruebaControlador.store','method'=>'POST'),array('id'=>'formularioajax')) !!}

                <div class="form-group">

                     {!! Form::label('', 'Nombre',array('id'=>'labelnombre')) !!}

                    {!! Form::text('nombre', old('nombre'), ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
                    {!!Form::token()!!}

                </div>

                <div class="form-group" id="ajaxdiv" >

                </div>

    {!! Form::submit('Validar Campos', ['id'=>'botonsubmit','class'=>'btn btn-default']) !!}

        {!! Form::close() !!}
```

FUNCIONES.JS

```
$('document').ready(function(){
        $('body').css('background','maroon');
        var ruta_completa= window.location.pathname;
        $('#botonsubmit').before(ruta_completa);

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                     }
                     });

        $('#botonsubmit').click(function(e){


            e.preventDefault();
                var nombre = $('input[name="nombre"]').val();
                var tokenvalue = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
                console.log(nombre);
                console.log('<br/>'+tokenvalue);

            $.ajax({

            url : ruta_completa,
            data : {'nombre': nombre,
                    //'_token':  tokenvalue
                },
            method: 'POST',

                    })
            .done(function(data) {
                console.log("success");
                var estilo = 'style="background : green; height : 30px; text-align:center; color:white; margin-top:20px "';
                var msgnotificacion =   '<div class="alert alert-success">';
                        msgnotificacion+=   '<a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>';
                        msgnotificacion+=   '<strong>REGISTRO '+nombre+' INSERTADO CORRECTAMENTE</strong>';
                    msgnotificacion+=   '</div>';

                     $('#labelnombre').after(msgnotificacion);
                     $('#botonsubmit').after('<p '+estilo+'>Nombre ..:: '+nombre+' ::.. </p>');

                            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR,thrownError) {
                console.log("error "+jqXHR.status);
                 if(xhr.status==404) {
                     console.log(thrownError);
                            }

                            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("complete");
                            });
        });


    });
```

RUTAS

```
Route::resource('pruebaControlador','PruebaController');
```

PRUEBACONTROLLER

(He eliminado los metodos vacios)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Requests\validaFormulario;
use Validator;

class PruebaController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {

        return view('pruebas.index');

    }

    public function store(validaFormulario $formulario)

    {


        $datosUsuarios = array(
                    'name' => $formulario->nombre,
                    'email' => 'default_'.rand(5555555,99999999).'@default.com',
                    'password' => bcrypt('1'),
            );

        \App\user::create($datosUsuarios);

        return response()->json($formulario->all());


    }

}
```

VALIDAFORMULARIO

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class validaFormulario extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'nombre' => 'required|min:2',
        ];
    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return array(
                    'nombre.required' => 'El campo :attribute es requerido',
                    'nombre.min' => 'El campo :attribute tiene un minimo de caracteres requeridos de 2 caracteres',
                );
    }
}
```

/***************************OTRO ERROR RELACIONADO***************************************/

Independientemente de si activo o no el csrf token, no muestra los mensajes que he especificado e la vista con este codigo

```
@if(count($errors))
                            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>

                            @foreach($errors->all() as $errores)
                                <p><strong>{{$errores}}</strong></p>
                            @endforeach
                            </div>
                        @endif
```

Esto, si lo hago enviando el formulario sin ajax funciona perfectamente pero con ajax no muestra los errores....aunque si hace la validacion(validaFormulario en controlador store, REQUEST PERSONALIZADO), es decir si esta el campo vacio,no muestra nada pero no inserta nada en la base de datos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agregar el campo respectivo al `<head>` de la vista implicada:

```
@push('head')
  <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
@endpush
```

Esto asumiendo que tengas algo así en tu template "global":

```
<head>
  @stack('head')
</head>
```

El resto es similar a lo que ya tienes:

Scripts al final de la página web:

```
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
```

Comment: Era eso, eran las dichosas cabeceras, me faltaba el meta, entonces el tema principal, esta resuelto, muchas gracias. Si me pudieras ayudar con el secundario te lo agredeceria, que es que los mensajes de validacion que valida el request personalizado, no se muestran usando ajax, aunque si que hace la validacion y si no cumples algo no te deja pasar. Gracias de nuevo.

Comment: Los errores no los muestra pq simplemente AJAX es JavaScript, entonces deberías tomar los errores que te entrega Laravel por medio de fail (algo similar a lo que ya haces con la excepción 404), y mostrar los mensajes vía Javascript.

Comment: Si, sé que ajax es javascript, el tema es que la fusion de tecnologias (en este caso php y javascript) me cuesta un poco .Practicamente tenia seguro que era por eso, investigaré un poco mas basandome en tus consejos. Muchas gracias por todo.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba agregando esto a tu formulario:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

**EDIT**

En este post que encontre te detallan como verificar tu formulario ajax

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/l5-tokenmismatchexception-with-ajax-post

Espero te ayude

Comment: Hola, eso ya lo tenia en de esta forma, 

 {!!Form::token()!!}

devuelve esto

    


<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="Zeu1TxgvEjBOp9gzcP7pFmx2wY5de9eHh3iH3dQN">

Comment: Siempre que yo envio data usando ajax le asigno un nombre a la ruta, trata de cambiar tu ruta por algo como esto: url : route('ruta_completa');

Comment: Muchas gracias, al final lo solucione agregando el meta en la cabecera.